# ArcGis Pro calculate a new conditional field based on numerical values in different field

Tags: python, conditional-statements, arcgis

In an ArcGIS pro layer's attribute table I have a column/field of numerical values ranging from 0-13,000 (with some empty cells) - lets call this field 1. I made **a new** empty field (type is text) that I want to return a 0 **if** the corresponding cell value in field 1 is less than 0.5 and a '1' if greater or equal to 0.5. I see that reclass can do this but it overwrites field 1 and I want to keep field 1 and populate field 2 with conditions described above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called 'reclassify' in the ArcGIS Pro toolbox which adds a new field based on a condition (it does not overwrite the original field).

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.